# SQL query to change backorder status of all products in WooCommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

In WooCommerce you can change the status of a product to allow backorders, the default setting is 'not allowed'. I have thousands of products on my shop and I rather not change it manually for all of them. 
Is there an SQL query that could do this for me directly in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running this query in mySql

```
 UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  meta_value = 'yes' WHERE meta_key = '_backorders';
```

This is not enough to achieve your purpose. Need to enable Manage stock as well.

Try running this query also if WooCommerce allow backorders global settings is not enabled.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  meta_value = 'yes' WHERE meta_key = '_manage_stock';
```

Need to update stock quantity as well

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  meta_value = 1000 WHERE meta_key = '_stock';
```

For stock status

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  meta_value = 'instock' WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The query did change the status in the back-end to back orders allowed but on the front end nothing changed, the products still show 'out of stock' and there's no add to cart button.

Comment: @TimonAndries Update quantity to a big number - check updated answer

Comment: Manage stock is enabled, the stock quantity is 1000 now, back orders are allowed in the back-end but still on the front end it shows 'sold out'. I thought it was maybe a cache issue but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Done that but the problem remains. I have no idea how this is possble. In the back-end product list the articles are still marked as sold out eventhough it also says there are a 1000 in stock. See screenshot [link](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/14/f52ab5e722b90f21c9a1fa2b03c1ad3b-full.jpg)

Comment: UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  meta_value = _stock_status WHERE meta_key = 'instock';

Comment: That query didn't do anything. I really appreciate the help tho!!

Comment: It works! I don't know if there's some kind of delay or what the problem was but now everything is like I'd wanted it to be. Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I am working with variable products, so I need to execute the below query as well:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'onbackorder' WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status';
```

Answer (score 0):

it's work.

```
$product = SELECT * FROM `wpuk_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'product';
foreach( $product as $pro){       
  $checknotify = SELECT * FROM `wpuk_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = '$pro->ID' AND `meta_key` = '_stock_status';
        
  if (empty($checknotify)) {
     INSERT INTO `wpuk_postmeta`(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('$pro->ID','_stock_status','onbackorder');
  } else {
     UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value = 'onbackorder' WHERE `post_id` = '$pro->ID' AND `meta_key` = '_stock_status';
  }
 }

UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value = 'yes' WHERE `meta_key` = '_manage_stock';
```

It is for Notification

```
$product = SELECT * FROM `wpuk_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'product'; // Optional
foreach( $product as $pro){   
$checknotify = SELECT * FROM `wpuk_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = '$pro->ID' AND `meta_key` = '_backorders';

if (empty($checknotify)) {
    INSERT INTO `wpuk_postmeta`(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('$pro->ID','_backorders','notify');
} else {
    UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '_backorders' WHERE `post_id` = '$pro->ID' AND `meta_key` = 'notify';
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

If u want to auto then Edit Plugin Code.

I try, and it's work.

Woocommerce Stock Edit File..
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php

Update It :

```
    'manage_stock'       => "yes",
    'backorders'         => "notify",
    'stock_status'       => "onbackorder",
```

[Like Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rekcx.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: **NEVER edit core files!** When WC gets updated, it overwrites the installation with any new updates included in the release. If the core has been chopped up and modified beforehand, it’ll wipe out those changes. That means big sections of the installation will just stop working. Modifying the core can have all kinds of unintended consequences, like preventing updates from working correctly, further screwing up an installation. Even worse is the potential to introduce unintended security vulnerabilities. Messing with core files could easily introduce a hole allowing hackers to take over a site